# Apache+Passenger doesn't work, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I try to setup Passenger in my Apache setup,

I get this error :

```
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    no such file to load -- config/environment
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /home/username/Sites/railsapp/ 
Backtrace:
    #   File   Line   Location
    0   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb   36   in `require'
    1   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb   36   in `require'
    2   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb   303   in `preload_application'
    3   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb   252   in `block in initialize_server'
    4   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   230   in `report_app_init_status'
    5   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb   237   in `initialize_server'
    6   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   193   in `start_synchronously'
    7   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   162   in `start'
    8   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb   213   in `start'
    9   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   261   in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
    10   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   126   in `lookup_or_add'
    11   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   255   in `block in spawn_rails_application'
    12   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   80   in `block in synchronize'
    13   < td=""> <>  prelude>   10:in `synchronize'
    14   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79   in `synchronize'
    15   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   254   in `spawn_rails_application'
    16   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   153   in `spawn_application'
    17   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   286   in `handle_spawn_application'
    18   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   351   in `main_loop'
    19   /etc/httpd/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   195   in `s  tart_synchronously'
    20   /etc/httpd/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server   61   in `'
```

my vhost apache config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName railsapp
   DocumentRoot "/home/username/Sites/railsapp/public "
   RailsEnv development
   PassengerAppRoot /home/username/Sites/railsapp/ 
   <Directory /home/username/Sites/railsapp/public/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't find why i get this error. If i run the app with WEBRick, everything works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you had a look at this answer> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732963/passenger-problem-no-such-file-to-load-config-environment? Sounds very much like the problem that you're having

Comment: Also, the VHost `Directory` section for apache 2.4 should look like ```
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```
Hard to tell if you are using 2.2. or 2.4. I only mention this here because I had some problems configuring Passenger with apache 2.4, and this was part of the solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file called `production.rb` in `/home/username/Sites/railsapp/config/environments`?  That seems to be missing as Passenger is running RAILS_ENV production.

WEBrick will be using `development.rb` in that folder as that is the RAILS_ENV being run.

Comment: Yes, i have a production.rb in my config/environments, this site work on the production host with passenger and apache. but i don't want to use WEBrick anymore, that's why i want to install Apache + Passenger. i have specified too RailsEnv in my vhost config

Answer (score 0):

Your `DocumentRoot` includes a space.

```
"/home/username/Sites/railsapp/public "
```

I would recommend not quoting this string.

```
/home/username/Sites/railsapp/public
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, my faut, i have removed the "" and i get the same error too